# How to make scrollView not jump up when textview is removed? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I have a scrollView that is constrained to a TextView above it. I also have a button next to that TextView that when pressed makes that Textview invisible. However when I press the button, the code works perfectly, but the scrollview overlaps the button and its own texts. Is there a way I could "double constrain" it to the button when the textview is not there? Or any other ways I would be able to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Probably there could be a way if you share the layout

Comment: If TextView is invisible, it is still there and will not cause dependent control move. Is it Gone instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to not fall into this issue like if you use visibility = Invisible instead of Gone:

```
textView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

Or You can just put the TextView and the Button in a CardView then constriant the CardView with the ScrollView (which will be outside of the CardView).

Comment: For the explication : Gone makes your item physically "Gone" which means it won't take any space in your View. Invisible is like changing the color of your item to transparent so you can't see it but it is still there.

Comment: I know but she might need to do the same, otherwise the CardView option is available

Comment: Ya, I just wanted to explain the difference between those two ^^. Some newbies may look at your answer not understand why :)